# Error with rendering webapp2

Tags: google-app-engine

Good personal day. I have a problem I can not solve.

It happens that in an app I am creating have 3 files: main, config and home.html

The config file is used to grab the User data and adds them to a dictionary. If the User does not exist in the datastore, he adds.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from google.appengine.api.app_identity import get_default_version_hostname
from google.appengine.ext import ndb


url = get_default_version_hostname()


# BANCO DE DADOS PARA SALVAR OS USUARIOS
class Usuarios(ndb.Model):
    usuario = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    openID = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    tipo = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def get_email(cls, email):
        return cls.query(cls.email == email)


########### FUNÇÃO QUE CHAMA O LOGIN ########
def Redir():
    from google.appengine.api import users
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if users.is_current_user_admin():
        redir = 'http://' + url + '/admin'
    else:
        redir = None

    return redir

def Geral():
    from google.appengine.api import users
    user = users.get_current_user()

    providers = {
        'Google' : 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id',
        'Yahoo'  : 'yahoo.com',
    }

    rt = {
        'titulo'    : 'BETA HCBravin',
        'version'   : '14.11.10',
        'url'       : 'http://' + url,
    }

    # O USUARIO ESTA LOGADO?
    if user:

        # O USUARIO E UM ADMINISTRADOR?
        if users.is_current_user_admin():
            dtipo = 'Admin'
        else:
            dtipo = 'Aluno'

        # O USUARIO EXISTE NO BANCO DE DADOS?
        quser = Usuarios.get_email(user.email())
        buser = quser.get()

        if not buser:
            dbuser = Usuarios(usuario = user.nickname(), email = user.email(), openID = user.user_id(), tipo = dtipo)
            dbuser.put()

        if buser:
            if buser.tipo == 'Professor':
                dtipo = 'Professor'
            else:
                dtipo = 'Aluno'

        rt.update({
            'usuario': user.nickname(),
            'email': user.email(),
            'openID': user.user_id(),
            'logout_url': users.create_logout_url('/'),
            'user_tipo': dtipo,
        })

    else:     # let user choose authenticator
        #login_url = {'usuario': None, 'logout_url': None}
        login_url = {}
        for name, uri in providers.items():
            login_url[name] = users.create_login_url(dest_url = ('/usuario') ,federated_identity=uri)

        rt.update(login_url)

    return rt
########## ############
```

The main file is the main file of my app that renders the home.html

```
import os
import webapp2
import sys


from config import *
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

Geral = Geral()

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):      
        self.response.out.write(template.render('home.html', Geral))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

The home.html only has a value that is to get the variable `{{ email }}` and print it (that's not all, logical. Bad am using the simplest approach)

The problem:
When I login with a User it perfectly shows email. But if I make out and User mute rather than appearing email "new" keeps popping up the old email.

This remains even if I refresh the page.

Comment: Not sure I understand what "make out and User mute" means.  Try going to your admin console, to Datastore Viewer, and clearing the memcache after you delete the user.  NDB caches some entities, so the user may still exist in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Code outside of your handler's methods only runs when an instance starts up, not once-per-request.
So your call `Geral = Geral()` isn't being repeated for visitors after the first one.

You should move that line inside your get method (and probably change the name on the left-hand-side to not be the same as the function-name!)